# Could not check annotations in eclipse rcp class loader

Tags: eclipse, annotations, rcp

I have the following code. It works on loading the class I pointed which is TestSuiteSample. TestSuiteSample is just a standard JUnit4 Test Suite with annotations. Running as normal java project this will print "true" but running under eclipse rcp this will print "false". Any ideas why?

```
File testSuiteDir = new File("D:/TestDir/");
URL classUrl; 
classUrl = testSuiteDir.toURI().toURL(); 
URL[] classUrls = { classUrl }; 
URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(classUrls); 
Class<?> cls = ucl.loadClass("TestSuiteSample"); 

if (cls.isAnnotationPresent(SuiteClasses.class)) { 
     System.out.println("true"); 
} else {
     System.out.println("false");
```

}

I tried this one to check for annotations in cls, but still returns 0 annotations.

```
Annotation[] annotations = new TestClass(clazz).getAnnotations();
for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
    System.out.println(annotation.annotationType().getName());
}
```

Comment: I added this one

this.getClass().getClassLoader() in creating new URLClassLoader.  Im not too sure if Thread.getCurrentThread().getContextClassLoader is the same as this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `SuiteClasses` class is coming from an unrelated `ClassLoader` than from the `URLClassLoader` you are using to load the class you are testing. If you make the parent of the `URLClassLoader` the bundle or thread context `ClassLoader` then it should resolve to the same class.

Comment: Correct me if im wrong. Inputting the parent classloader will point to the correct class say for SuiteClasses?

Comment: You want to have the SuiteClasses resolved through the same ClassLoader chain you loaded the class, otherwise they are in two different worlds and you can't compare the class objects. That's why you need to hook the normal classloader chain to your URLClassLoader.